# Error while trying to get the second minimum record in a group

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

```
df.groupby('ID')['date'].nsmallest(2).groupby(level='ID').last()
```

This is the code I used. It seems to not work and throwing me an error.

```
ID  Date
123  2016-09-11 
123  2018-09-30
123  2017-06-28
```

My output should be

```
ID   Date
123  2017-06-28
```

I am not sure why my code is not working. Can someone help?

```
TypeError: nsmallest() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute '_aggregate_item_by_item'
```

dtype('